# '$' is undefined in a script at the bottom of a web forms content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I'm getting the above error in the following jquery script:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#custSubmit').submit(function () {
            var user = {
                email: $('#custEmail').val(),
                password: $('#custPassword').val()
            };
            $.post("http://blahblahblah", user, function (data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
            $('#custEmail').val('');
            $('#custPassword').val('');
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

I've been staring at it for a minute and my jquery is a bit weak. All my other jquery seems to be working correctly. Can someone help me see what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure jQuery is included correctly, can you open the console `F12` and check `jQuery` is defined?

Comment: Perhaps you've included another script before that point, one that calls `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: Where did you include jQuery?

Comment: Included jquery on the master page at the bottom of the body.

Comment: @Rex_C Is it included before this script is?

Comment: @Rex_C: If you don't include jQuery until after this code executes then `$` hasn't been defined yet.  JavaScript executes in the order in which it loads.  You need to *include* jQuery before you can *use* jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an HTML document, scripts are run in the order in which they are encountered. If your `<script>` tag to include jQuery appears just before the end of your body tag, but this content is included before that, then jQuery (and `$`) won't be available when this script tag is evaluated.

Either move your call to jQuery higher up in the body, or rethink the way that you define your script dependencies so that you're not including items which depend on jQuery until it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this type of error is due to the jquery library not being loaded and/or the relevant code being called before jquery is loaded. Check the rendered HTML and ensure a script tag loading jquery (e.g. `<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>`) is present.